# Cartesian product of sets proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let A,B and C be some arbitrary sets.Prove the given equation :

(A \ B) x C = (A x C) \ (B x C) , where x stands for Cartesian product of sets.

I don't know how to start. Could you please help me with this problem...

Comment: You can start applying the definitions.

Answer (score 3):

A point in the set on the left looks like $(x,y)$ where $x \in A \setminus B$ and $y \in C$. This means that $x \in A$, $x \notin B$ and $y \in C$.

Thus, $(x,y) \in A \times C$ but $(x,y) \notin B \times C$.

So, $(x,y) = (A \times C) \setminus (B \times C)$.

You can finish up with the other direction similarly.